# SSE value calculated in C++ eigen is different from true value

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am a beginner of C++. Any help will be very appreciated!
I can successfully compile and run the following code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  MatrixXf m1(10,1);
  m1 << 50,51,52,54,53,60,59,65,67,70;
  MatrixXf m3(3,10);
  MatrixXf m2(10,3);
  m3<< 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,     //Xf[,5:6]
       54,61,52,70,63,0,0,0,0,0,
       0,0,0,0,0,79,68,65,79,76;
  m2 << m3.transpose();
  MatrixXf I(10,10);
  I.setIdentity(10,10);
  float SSE =(m1.transpose()*(I-m2*(m2.transpose()*m2).inverse()*m2.transpose())*m1).determinant();
  std::cout << "SSE=" << std::endl;
  std::cout << SSE << std::endl << std::endl;
  system("pause");
}
```

SSE worked out in C++:**87.7938**，while SSE true value:**88.29133**

Comment: Can you post your compiler options? I'm thinking you have -fast-math or -fp-relaxed active.

Comment: Where did you get the "true value" from?

Comment: Try `MatrixXd` for more precision. Float errors can accumulate very fast, especially if you do transformations that have intermediate values that are very small or very large.

Comment: @MarcGlisse    I got the "true value" from R software and SAS software.

Comment: @VAndrei    Sorry,I have no right to post compiler options images. And the problem is to convert MatrixXf into MatrixXd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MatrixXd instead of MatrixXf